# How would I fix pygame's key press event not doing anything?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, 2d-games

I'm setting up this class that has the purpose of setting up the character and drawing them on to the game. The key press is in another loop inside a function. Now while I do have the sprites I'm having difficulties using those sprites whenever I try to press the button responsible for the attack.

I have tried changing around a few things such as changing the button that makes the attack animation show. I've also added a variable that is set to true whenever the button is pressed and false whenever another button is pressed.

```
#Sprite Image Load
    #18
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('Moving1.png'), pygame.image.load('Moving2.png'), pygame.image.load('Moving3.png'), pygame.image.load('Moving4.png'), pygame.image.load('Moving5.png'), pygame.image.load('Moving6.png'), pygame.image.load('Moving7.png'), pygame.image.load('Moving8.png'), pygame.image.load('Moving9.png')]
walkRight = []
Jump18 = [pygame.image.load('18Jump1.png'), pygame.image.load('18Jump2.png'), pygame.image.load('18Jump3.png'), pygame.image.load('18Jump4.png'), pygame.image.load('18Jump5.png'), pygame.image.load('18Jump6.png'), pygame.image.load('18Jump7.png') ] 
Punch18 = [pygame.image.load('18Punch1.png'), pygame.image.load('18Punch2.png'), pygame.image.load('18Punch3.png'), pygame.image.load('18Punch4.png'), pygame.image.load('18Punch5.png')]

for i in walkLeft:
    walkRight.append(pygame.transform.flip(i, True, False))

for x in range(len(walkLeft)):
    walkLeft[x] = pygame.transform.smoothscale(walkLeft[x], (311, 412))

for x in range(len(walkRight)):
    walkRight[x] = pygame.transform.smoothscale(walkRight[x], (311, 412))

for x in range(len(Jump18)):
    Jump18[x] = pygame.transform.smoothscale(Jump18[x], (311, 412))

for x in range(len(Punch18)):
    Punch18[x] = pygame.transform.smoothscale(Punch18[x], (311, 412))    



char = pygame.image.load('Moving1.png').convert_alpha()
char = pygame.transform.smoothscale(char, (372, 493))
char2 = pygame.image.load('Moving1.png').convert_alpha()
char2 = pygame.transform.smoothscale(char2, (372, 493))
char2 = pygame.transform.flip(char2, True, False)





x = 0
y = 407
height = 40
width = 87
vel = 12
isJump = False
jumpCount = 10
left = False
right = False
walkCount = 0
attackCount = 0
standing = False
jumpStore = 0
attack1 = False
run = True

# === CLASSES === (CamelCase names)

class Enemy(object):
    walkLeftGB = [pygame.image.load('GB1.png'), pygame.image.load('GB2.png'), pygame.image.load('GB3.png'), pygame.image.load('GB4.png'), pygame.image.load('GB5.png'), pygame.image.load('GB6.png'), pygame.image.load('GB7.png'), pygame.image.load('GB8.png'),pygame.image.load('GB9.png') ]
    walkRightGB = []

    for i in walkLeftGB:
        walkRightGB.append(pygame.transform.flip(i, True, False))

    for x in range(len(walkLeftGB)):
        walkLeftGB[x] = pygame.transform.smoothscale(walkLeftGB[x], (311, 412))

    for x in range(len(walkRightGB)):
        walkRightGB[x] = pygame.transform.smoothscale(walkRightGB[x], (311, 412))

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, end):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.path = [x, end]
        self.walkCount = 0
        self.vel = 5

    def move(self):
        if self.vel > 0:
            if self.x < self.path[0] + self.vel - 30:
                self.x += self.vel
            else:
                self.vel = self.vel * -1
                self.x += self.vel
                self.walkCount = 0
        else:
            if self.x > self.path[0] - W + 300 - self.vel:
                self.x += self.vel
            else:
                self.vel = self.vel * -1
                self.x += self.vel
                self.walkCount = 0

    def draw(self, DS):
        self.move()
        if self.walkCount + 1 >= 27:
            self.walkCount = 0
        if self.vel > 0:
            DS.blit(self.walkRightGB[self.walkCount//9], (self.x,self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1
        else:
            DS.blit(self.walkLeftGB[self.walkCount//9], (self.x,self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1


class Android18(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 5
        self.isJump = False
        self.left = False
        self.right = False
        self.walkCount = 0
        self.jumpCount = 10
        self.jumpStore = 0
        self.attackCount = 0
        self.standing = True
        self.attack1 = False


    def draw(self, DS):
        if self.walkCount + 1 >= 27:
            self.walkCount = 0

        if self.attackCount + 1 >=10:
            self.attackCount = 0

        if self.jumpStore + 1 >= 16:
            self.jumpStore = 0

        if not(self.standing):
            if self.right:
                DS.blit(walkRight[self.walkCount//9], (self.x,self.y))
                self.walkCount += 1
            elif self.left:
                DS.blit(walkLeft[self.walkCount//9], (self.x,self.y))
                self.walkCount +=1
            elif self.attack1:
                DS.blit(Punch18[self.attackCount//5], (self.x,self.y))

        else:
            if self.left:
                DS.blit(walkLeft[0], (self.x, self.y))
            else:
                DS.blit(walkRight[0], (self.x, self.y))



"""
        if (self.standing):
            if self.isJump:
                DS.blit(Jump18[self.jumpStore//8], (self.x,self.y))
                self.jumpStore +=1

            elif self.isJump:
                DS.blit(Jump18[self.jumpStore//8], (self.x,self.y))
                self.jumpStore +=1
                #self.walkCount+=1
"""
            #self.jumpCount = 10



class Button():
    def __init__(self, text, x=0, y=0, width=100, height=50, command=None):

        self.text = text
        self.command = command
        self.image_normal = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image_normal.fill(green)
        self.image_hovered = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image_hovered.fill(grey)
        self.image  = self.image_normal
        self.rect   = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

        self.hovered= False  # is the mouse over this button?

    def update(self):
        pass

    def handleMouseOver( self, mouse_position ):
        """ If the given co-ordinate inside our rect,
            Do all the mouse-hovering work             """
        # Check button position against mouse
        # Change the state *once* on entry/exit
        if ( self.mouseIsOver( mouse_position ) ):
            if ( self.hovered == False ):
                self.image = self.image_hovered
                self.hovered = True   # edge-triggered, not level triggered
                # Do we want to check pygame.mixer.get_busy() ?
                if ( pygame.mixer.get_busy() == False ):
                    buttonsound1.play()
                    print("Hovering above")
        else:
            if ( self.hovered == True ):
                self.image = self.image_normal
                self.hovered = False

    def mouseIsOver( self, mouse_position ):
        """ Is the given co-ordinate inside our rect """
        return self.rect.collidepoint( mouse_position )

    def draw(self, surface):

        surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)




class GameState( enum.Enum ):
    Loading = 0
    Menu = 1
    Settings = 2
    Playing = 3
    GameOver = 4



# FUNCTIONS
def event_handler():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            pygame.quit()
            exit()











#set the game state initially.
game_state = GameState.Loading


#LOADING
def text_objects(text, color, size):
    if size == "small":
        textSurface = smallfont.render(text, True, color)

    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def loading(progress):
    if progress < 100:
        text = smallfont.render("Loading: " + str(int(progress)) + "%", True, WHITE)
    else:
        text = smallfont.render("Loading: " + str(100) + "%", True, WHITE)

    DS.blit(text, [50, 660])

def message_to_screen(msh, color, y_displace = 0, size = "small"):
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, color, size)
    textRect.center = HW, HH + y_displace
    DS.blit(textSurf, textRect)

while (progress/4) < 100:
    event_handler()
    DS.blit(loadingimg, (0,0))
    time_count = (random.randint(1,1))
    increase = random.randint(1,20)
    progress += increase
    pygame.draw.rect(DS, green, [50, 700, 402, 29])
    pygame.draw.rect(DS, grey, [50, 701, 401, 27])
    if (progress/4) > 100:
        pygame.draw.rect(DS, green, [50, 700, 401, 28])
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(DS, green, [50, 700, progress, 28])
    loading(progress/4)
    pygame.display.flip()

    time.sleep(0.01)





def main_menu():
    #Menumusic = pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)
    game_state = GameState.Menu
    DS.blit(mainmenu, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()
    run = True
    btn1 = Button('Arcade Mode', 545,  231, 525, 113)
    btn2 = Button('Vs Mode',  240, 371, 1121, 115)
    btn3 = Button('Instructions', 542, 488, 531, 109)
    btn4 = Button('Options', 605, 606, 342, 116)
    btn5 = Button('Exit game', 579, 726, 395, 111)
    # Put the buttons into a list so we can loop over them, simply
    buttons = [ btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5 ]

    if (pygame.mixer.get_busy() == False) or (pygame.mixer.get_busy() == True) :
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()
            pygame.mixer.music.load("MainMenu.mp3")
            print("Music playing")
            pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)

    while run:
        event_handler
        # draw the buttons
        #for b in buttons:
            #b.draw( DS ) # --- draws ---

        # Handle events
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                mouse_position = event.pos
                for b in buttons:
                    b.handleMouseOver( mouse_position )
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mouse_position = event.pos
                for b in buttons:
                    if ( b.mouseIsOver( mouse_position ) ):
                        print('Clicked:', b.text)

                        if b.text == "Arcade Mode":
                            mouseclick1.play()
                            print("Arcade mode has been clicked")
                            arcade_mode()

                        elif b.text == "Vs Mode":
                            mouseclick1.play()
                            print("Vs mode has been clicked")


                        elif b.text == "Instructions":
                            mouseclick1.play()
                            print("Instructions mode has been clicked")
                            instructions_mode()

                        elif b.text == "Options":
                            mouseclick1.play()
                            print("options has been clicked")


                        elif b.text == "Exit game":
                            mouseclick1.play()
                            run = False
                            pygame.quit()
                            print("Exit button pressed")
                        print('Sound Effect')
                if game_state != 1:
                    run = False





        pygame.display.update()



def instructions_mode():
    DS.blit(instructions, (0,0))
    pygame.display.update()
    run = False
    instructions1 = True
    counter = 0
    exitbutton = Button('Exit', 719, 737, 165, 72)
    arrow = Button('Arrow', 1108, 732, 120, 68)

    arrow1 = pygame.image.load("arrow.png")
    arrow1 = pygame.transform.smoothscale(arrow1, (120, 68))

    box1 = pygame.image.load("Box1.png").convert_alpha()
    box1 = pygame.transform.smoothscale(box1, (1222,706))

    box2 = pygame.image.load("Box2.png").convert_alpha()
    box2 = pygame.transform.smoothscale(box2, (1222,706))

    box3 = pygame.image.load("Box3.png").convert_alpha()
    box3 = pygame.transform.smoothscale(box3, (1222,706))

    box4 = pygame.image.load("Box4.png").convert_alpha()
    box4 = pygame.transform.smoothscale(box4, (1222,706))

    box5 = pygame.image.load("Box5.png").convert_alpha()
    box5 = pygame.transform.smoothscale(box5, (1222,706))




    while instructions1:
        event_handler()
        if (pygame.mixer.get_busy() == True):
            pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.2)
        if counter == 0:
            DS.blit(box1, (182,88))
            DS.blit(arrow1,(1108, 710))
            DS.blit(exit1, (719, 737))
            pygame.display.update()

        elif counter == 1:
            DS.blit(box2, (182,88))
            pygame.display.update()

        elif counter == 2:
            DS.blit(box3, (182,88))
            pygame.display.update()

        elif counter == 3:
            DS.blit(box4, (182,88))
            pygame.display.update()

        elif counter == 4:
            DS.blit(box5, (182,88))
            pygame.display.update()


        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                instructions1 = False
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                mouse_position = event.pos
                arrow.handleMouseOver( mouse_position )
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mouse_position = event.pos
                if ( arrow.mouseIsOver( mouse_position ) ):
                        print('Clicked:', arrow.text)
                        print('Sound Effect')
                        counter +=1
                        mouseclick1.play()
                if ( exitbutton.mouseIsOver( mouse_position ) ):
                    print("Instructiona Exited")
                    mouseclick1.play()
                    instructions1 = False
                    main_menu()


def arcade_mode():
    DS.blit(arcadescreen, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()
    run = False
    arcade = True


    char1 = Button('Goku Black', 125,  144, 261, 189)
    char2 = Button('Gohan',  500, 152, 165, 178)
    char3 = Button('Vegeta', 758, 146, 340, 189)
    char4 = Button('Goku', 1148, 146, 337, 193)
    char5 = Button('Android 18', 129, 393, 257, 261)

    exitbutton = Button('Exit', 134, 800, 267, 75)
    leaderboard = Button('Leaderboard',557, 786, 529, 114)


    fightbutton = Button('Fight', 1320, 785, 256, 117)

    characters = [ char1, char2, char3, char4, char5 ]
    limiter = 0

    cx, cy = 669,746


    if (pygame.mixer.get_busy() == True):
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()
            pygame.mixer.music.load("ArcadeMode.mp3")
            print("Music playing")
            pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)

    while arcade:
        event_handler() 
        DS.blit(exit1, (134, 800))
        DS.blit(leaderboard1, (557, 786))
        DS.blit(fight, (1320, 785))
        pygame.display.update()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                arcade = False
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                mouse_position = event.pos
                for b in characters:
                    b.handleMouseOver( mouse_position )
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mouse_position = event.pos
                for b in characters:
                    if ( b.mouseIsOver( mouse_position ) ):
                        print('Clicked:', b.text)

                        if b.text == "Goku Black" and limiter == 0:
                            mouseclick1.play()
                            print("Goku Black: Selected")
                            limiter += 1
                            text1 = largefont.render(b.text + ': Selected', True, WHITE, None)
                            DS.blit(text1,(cx,cy))

                        elif b.text == "Gohan" and limiter == 0:
                            mouseclick1.play()
                            print("Gohan: Selected")
                            limiter += 1
                            text1 = largefont.render(b.text + ': Selected', True, WHITE, None)
                            DS.blit(text1,(cx,cy))

                        elif b.text == "Vegeta" and limiter == 0:
                            mouseclick1.play()
                            print("Vegeta: Selected")
                            limiter += 1
                            text1 = largefont.render(b.text + ': Selected', True, WHITE, None)
                            DS.blit(text1,(cx,cy))

                        elif b.text == "Goku" and limiter == 0:
                            mouseclick1.play()
                            print("Goku Selected")
                            limiter += 1
                            text1 = largefont.render(b.text + ': Selected', True, WHITE, None)
                            DS.blit(text1,(cx,cy))

                        elif b.text == "Android 18" and limiter == 0:
                            mouseclick1.play()
                            print("Android 18: Selected")
                            limiter += 1
                            text1 = largefont.render(b.text + ': Selected', True, WHITE, None)
                            DS.blit(text1,(cx,cy))

                        pygame.display.update()

                    if ( exitbutton.mouseIsOver( mouse_position ) ):
                        print("Arcade Exited")
                        mouseclick1.play()
                        arcade = False
                        main_menu()

                    if ( leaderboard.mouseIsOver( mouse_position ) ):
                        print("Leaderboard Clicked")
                        mouseclick1.play()
                        leaderboard_screen()

                    if ( fightbutton.mouseIsOver( mouse_position ) ):
                        print("Fight Clicked")
                        mouseclick1.play()
                        fight_mode()


man = Enemy(1300, 489, 311, 412, 1600)
Char18 = Android18(0, 489, 311, 412)  

def redrawGameWindow():
    global walkCount
    DS.blit(canyon,(0,0))
    lastMoved = "left"
    man.draw(DS)
    Char18.draw(DS)
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.display.flip()






def fight_mode():
    fight = True
    arcade = False
    progress = 0
    global isJump, jumpCount
    global x,y, vel
    global width, height
    global left, right
    px, py, speed = HW, HH, 10
    if (pygame.mixer.get_busy() == True):
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()

    while fight:
        while(progress/4) < 100:
            event_handler()
            DS.fill(BLACK)
            time_count = (random.randint(1,1))
            increase = random.randint(1,20)
            progress += increase
            pygame.draw.rect(DS, green, [50, 700, 402, 29])
            pygame.draw.rect(DS, grey, [50, 701, 401, 27])
            if (progress/4) > 100:
                pygame.draw.rect(DS, green, [50, 700, 401, 28])
            else:
                pygame.draw.rect(DS, green, [50, 700, progress, 28])
            loading(progress/4)
            pygame.display.flip()

            time.sleep(0.2)
        redrawGameWindow()
        CLOCK.tick(FPS)
        event_handler()
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_a] and Char18.x > Char18.vel:
            Char18.x -= Char18.vel
            Char18.left = True
            Char18.right = False
            Char18.standing =  False
        elif keys[pygame.K_d] and Char18.x < W - Char18.width - Char18.vel:
            Char18.x+= Char18.vel
            Char18.standing = False
            Char18.right = True
            Char18.left = False
        else:
            Char18.right = False
            Char18.left = False
            Char18.standing = True
            Char18.walkCount = 0

        if not(Char18.isJump):
            if keys[pygame.K_w]:
                Char18.isJump = True
                Char18.walkCount = 0
                Char18.jumpStore += 10

        else:
            if Char18.jumpCount >= -10:
                neg = 2
                if Char18.jumpCount < 0:
                    neg = -2
                Char18.y-= (Char18.jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
                Char18.jumpCount -= 1
            else:
                Char18.isJump = False
                Char18.jumpCount = 10
                Char18.jumpStore += 10
        if keys[pygame.K_h]:
            Char18.attack1 = True
            Char18.attackCount = 0
        elif keys[pygame.K_j]:
            Char18.attack1 = False
            #Char18.attack2 = True



        pygame.display.update()
```

I expect the character to react by displaying the attack animation but it instead does nothing, there's no error from the console too.

Comment: You have to modify the state on the character object. Not some global variables.

Comment: where do you have instance of `Android18` ? Where do you use it ? How do you change it ? I don't see it. You can always use `print()` in many places to see which part of code is executed and what values you have in variables.

Comment: Oh no I do have the instance, just that I don't show it here. I only took the significant bits from my code and put it here so that I got straight to the point and not waste anyone else's time reading through it.

Comment: You ARE wasting everyone’s time showing code that’s not particular to the problem. Yes, it’s encouraged to simplify the problems here. But they must still work.

Comment: `attack1` and `walkCount` are _local_ variables in the `fight_mode()` function, as have no effect and don't exist outside it. It's also unclear what `Char18` is. Without seeing more of the relevant code, it's impossible to give you more of a definitive answer.

Comment: There, fixed it removed the minor mistake made

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the difference between local variables and class member variables.

Basically the code should look like this:

```
char18 = Android18()
...

while main_looping:
    ...
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_h]:
        char18.attack1 = True   # <-- HERE
    elif keys[pygame.K_j]:
        char18.attack1 = False  # <-- AND HERE
        char18.attack2 = True
```

Note that this version of the code is not setting `attack1 = True`, but `char18.attack1 = True`.  This is referencing the variable *inside* the `char18` object, not a local (or global - we can't tell from the question).

These variables needed to be set *inside* the object to match the inner-workings of it, not local variables to the `fight_mode()` function, or globals.  Maybe have a read-up on [variable scope](https://pythonspot.com/scope/).  The variable `attack1` inside `main_looping()` is not the same variable as `Android18.attack1`.  The object is "hiding" (encapsulating) these variables inside itself.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that I made that mistake, however when I tried to re-run the code after correcting them, It just did not want to work for some reason

Answer (score 0):

The code for the button clicks is wrong to me.
You should try this:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        btn_clicked = False
        if pos[0] in range(button_x1, button_x2) and pos[1] in range(button_y1, button_y2):
            btn_clicked = True
        if btn_clicked:
            # do something
```

That code maybe will solve your button problem, and I say @Kingsley's solution is correct.